# VARINT vs BIGINT in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I want to know when to use VARINT instead of BIGINT?
What is the limitation of each of them and how much space is being used by VARINT?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) the `bigint` is a 64bit signed integer, whereas `varint` is an arbitrary precision integer, corresponding to the `BigInteger` type in java.